# Method not run in java listener actionPerformed

Tags: java, awt, listener, actionlistener

I have a method myFuncs.requestData() that works standalone. It subcribes to listen for data and sets ReadyTxt="TRUE" when the listener has received all the data - which comes in multiple callbacks.

But, when I try to to check DataReady within the actionPerformed method that is attached to a button - it is unset because it appears that myFuncs.requestData() is only processed/run AFTER we come out of actionPerformed.

By "standalone" I mean that if I put no function at ##HERE## then the requestData() works after actionPerformed has completed.

How can I make sure it runs and wait for it to finish at the point ##HERE##?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    writePaneln("BUTTON PRESSED "+myFuncs.ReadyTxt);

    myFuncs.requestData();

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    writePaneln("REQUESTED "+myFuncs.ReadyTxt);

            ##HERE##
    }
```

Threaded version:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    writePaneln("BUTTON PRESSED "+myFuncs.ReadyTxt);

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run(){
                 myFuncs.requestData();
                    }
    };

    thread.start();

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    writePaneln("REQUESTED "+myFuncs.ReadyTxt);

            ##HERE##
    }
```

simplified requestData():

```
public void requestData() {

            DataReady="FALSE"
    this.dataSubscription.setListener(this);


}


@Override
public void dataUpdated(List<long> updatedData) {


    if (updatedData.size() <= 1 ){
        this.dataSubscription.destroy();

        writePaneln("In dataUpdated DataReady num: "+Dates.size());
        DataReady="TRUE";
        return;
    }

    for (long l: updatedData){
            writePaneln(l);
        Dates.add(l);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think more clarification is needed - what do you mean `myFuncs.requestData()` is run after you come out of `actionPerformed()` has completed?  Are you calling `myFuncs.requestData()` anywhere else?  Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Can you provide the code within `requestData`. It is hard to tell why it wouldn't work without having more details. Off the top of my head, I would guess that everything is running on the same thread.

Comment: @StormeHawke what I mean is that no matter how long I "sleep" requestData() does not run until after actionPerformed has completed (I can tell that because my writePaneln("REQUESTED") writes before requestData() does)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to make a wild guess here for lack of other data, but are you trying to run multiple threads here? If so you'll need to add some `syncrhonized` and create some locks to prevent multithreading issues

Comment: I tried running as a thread but it still has same results - see above

Comment: Your question really needs to be clearer. Provide more code (`requesData` code would help a lot), are you doing multiple-threads and "working standalone" is unclear still. We can all take wild guesses but that is wasting time.

Comment: Understood - problem is requestData is quite complex

Comment: And if you just make `requestData` change `ReadyTxt` to `true`, and nothing else, does it shows `true` when `writePaneln` is called in either the threaded or not version?

Comment: I have added simple version of the code. I tried your test and it still shows true AFTER actionPerformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer seems to lie in using TimerTask to time a task for AFTER actioPerformed has completely finished becuase it seems to be on single thread.

http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html